# Navbar-right interfering with navbar-collapse

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

So I want the navigation in the `nav-bar` to be right aligned, which works fine, but when the screen-size shrinks to where the button appears, the button doesn't work.
How can that be?

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-inverse">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="navbar-header">
            <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#myNavbar">
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            </button>
            <a class="navbar-brand" href="#"><img src="~/logo.gif" id="logo" /></a>
        </div>
        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse navbar-right">
            <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                <li class="active"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Page 1</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Page 2</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Page 3</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
</nav>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Learn to use the class of navbar components at [Navbar component](http://getbootstrap.com/components/#navbar)

Your code

```
<button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#myNavbar">

<div class="collapse navbar-collapse navbar-right">
<ul class="nav navbar-nav">
```

and the right code is

```
<div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="myID4Collapse">
  <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
```

the `navbar-right` must to be called into the `<ul>` -> `<ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">`

and you missing the id into the div for collapse into you code

`data-target="#myNavbar"` -> `id="#myNavbar"`

see the example working

[Navbar component](https://jsfiddle.net/92h3Lt6g/)

Comment: That makes a lot of sense. - Thanks for your reply.!